# What happened to psutils?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

Earlier this year I was able to install psutils package on RHEL with yum.
Now I am getting "No package psutils available."
Is there a way to find out what happened to it and if there is a possibility of it coming back?

Comment: Does "yum search postscript" list a likely package rename? CentOS 8 stil calls it psutils.

Comment: I didn't find it. I also tried "yum whatprovides psselect" because psselect is the command I am installing the package for.

Comment: look at  [Red Hat's package migration page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_8/index). RHEL 8.2 contains python38-psutils; earlier versions have simply dropped it. If you can't go to 8.2, try downloading from CentOS.